# Determining the projective closure of a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the twisted curve in $\Bbb{C}^3$ denoted by the ideal $\langle x^2-y, z-xy\rangle$

I did it by homogenizing the generators: I got $\langle x^2-yw, zw-xy\rangle$.

The projective closure seems to contain $x=w=0$. Which means the line parametrized by $z,w$ is here in the projective closure. However, my book says that this line does not form part of the closure. Why is that?

Comment: One thing that definitely tells you this is wrong is that the closure of an irreducible set is irreducible, so you can't pick up another component like this.

Answer (score 1):

To homogenize an ideal, you must homogenize a Gröbner basis for it. In M2:

```
R=QQ[x,y,z]
I=ideal(y-x^2,z-x*y)
gens gb I -- | y2-xz xy-z x2-y |
```

We see that this adds the generator $y^2-xz$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751887/calculating-the-projective-closure-with-more-than-one-generator).